# How to copy files in an emulator

Tags: android

I tried lots of solutions suggested on Stackoverflow to upload on an emulator.
I need it to test a feature where I can import data from a file.
Everything I tried didn't work:

- Drag & drop: yes the file is there, but I cannot see it if I open Download on emulator.
- Put it on sdcard with upload from Device File Explorer: I can't see it
- Download it from my Google Drive: the browser fails continuosly when I press download

At some point I have been able to find them, but I cannot select them (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE41R.jpg) ).
I am starting to think that this whole "emulator thing" is quite full of bugs...
Did someone have the same experience?
How did you fix?
The only thing that comes to my mind is to test using my real device...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a user answering to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/tk3nmn/weekly_questions_thread_march_22_2022/i2peoie/?context=3) "cross-post" on reddit, I switched to use
[Fuck-Storage-Access-Framework](https://github.com/K1rakishou/Fuck-Storage-Access-Framework).

This doesn't solve the question, but it solves the problem I had: allowing the user to select a file. With FSAF I can see the files I moved to the emulator.

Comment: You don't need this 'framework'. The official Android developer documentation clearly explains how to perform all of the common file storage operations. Also, if you look at the source code you'll see they are just using very common Android APIs.