# How to allow selection of CSV in a File Chooser Intent in Android

Tags: android, filechooser

after struggling one day I found this code "almost" works:

```
    private fun showFileChooser() {
        val mimeTypes = arrayOf(
            "text/csv",
            "text/plain",
            "application/csv",
            "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "application/excel",
            "application/x-excel",
            "application/x-msexcel"
        )

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "text/csv" //if (mimeTypes.size == 1) mimeTypes[0] else "*/*"
        if (mimeTypes.isNotEmpty())
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
        startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "choose file"),
            MY_RESULT_CODE_FILECHOOSER
        )
    }
```

The problem is that `*.csv` files cannot be selected/opened ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE41R.jpg) is a screenshot taken for another issue where you can see how the file appears... it is light gray like it is disable and indeed it cannot be selected)
Thanks to the mime type `text/plain` I am able to select `*.txt` files.
I found lots of posts here on StackOverflow with suggestions that do not work (probably anymore).
Is there any solution to this?
Regards

Comment: According to Stackoverflow policies, I have to mark this as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652215/how-to-copy-files-in-an-emulator).
Basically the world of filechooser in Android is really complex and using that library helps a lot in hiding that complexity.

Comment: I suggest just deleting your other question. It's much more vague and your 'solution' is sub-optimal, since Android already provides a means to do what you want without using a third-party 'framework'. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` you need to call `setType("*/*")`. See the [OpenFile](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#OpenFile) section of Common Intents.

Also, you should consider using the [Activity Results API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) instead of `startActivityForResult()` since it provides more type safety and the latter has been deprecated. The one you are looking for is [ActivityResultContracts.GetContent](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.GetContent)